# Python mutable/immutable and local variables

Tags: python, immutability

I am quite confused about a difference in behavior of the two following code snippets, and in particular about expectations of their behavior in the mutability/immutability in Python concept:

Snippet 1

```
def some_function_1(x):
  x[0] = 42

input = (3,)
_ = some_function_1(input)
print(input)
```

Which produces `TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment`, which I understand on the grounds of tuples being immutable. This is OK. But ...

Snippet 2

```
def some_function_2(x):
  x = 42

input = (3,)
_ = some_function_2(input)
print(input)
```

Which ... *1]* does NOT complain/crash regarding at attempt of altering (an immutable!) `x` - in contrast with the previous snippet *2]*  prints the `input` as the initial `(3,)`, i.e., as if the `input` were not "exposed" in any way to the action being taken inside of the assignment of the body of `some_function_2`.

Why the difference? What's happening here? Why is the non-mutability of tuples showing only in the 1st snippet?

Comment: The key here is to understand the difference between **modifying an object** vs **reassigning a name to refer to a new object**: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html. The section under *"Fact: References can be more than just names"* in that guide goes into detail about what's happening when you do something like `x[0] = 42`.

Comment: I was about to link to the exact same article. It's key python knowledge.

Comment: @slothrop Thanks a lot, that is a very valuable article, indeed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that hopefully makes it easier to understand:

```py
x = (1, 2)

def func1():
    x[0] = 42 # doesn't work

def func2():
    x = (3, 4, 5) # does work!
```

When you write `x[0] = something`, the script finds the value in memory that `x` is pointing to and attempts to modify it.

But when you do `x = something`, the script creates a new object in memory and makes `x` point to that new object instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. you are modifying the existing behavior of object x, ie tuple
2. you overwrite an existing object and give it a new definition/behavior. by overwriting i mean x which is assigned to the tuple now assigned to the 42, and since x already present in the memory so it overwrite existing behaviour, and the value of tuple which was previously assigned to will be handle by GC

Comment: *"you overwrite an existing object and give it a new definition/behavior."* The existing object isn't overwritten - in fact, `x = 42` does nothing at all to the object that `x` previously referred to. However, the garbage collector will most likely soon zap it if no other name refers to it.

Comment: _"you overwrite an existing object"_ I think that could be better phrased as "you are rebinding which object a variable references"

Comment: by overwriting i mean x which is assigned to the tuple now assigned to the 42, and since x already present in the memory so it overwrite existing behaviour, and the value of tuple which was previously assigned to will be handle by GC

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `x` is basically just a reference to an object.
In the first code block, you are trying to alter the object that is represented by `x`, which is a tuple.
As you correctly stated, a tuple is immutable in Python, which means that you can not directly change which items are contained within the tuple.
You could, however, change an object within the tuple, as long as the object is still the same.

```py
class Test123:
    abc = 10

a = Test123()
b = Test123()

print(a is b)
# --> False, as this is a different object and hence has a different identity

x = (a, )

# 1. Alter the tuple, doesn't work
x[0] = b
# --> Throws an error, as you're trying to change an immutable object

# 2. Alter the object within the tuple, works
x[0].abc = 123

# 3. Reassign x to another object, also works
old_x = x
x = (a, )

print(old_x is x)
# --> False, as old_x and x are not the same object (identity-wise)
print(old_x == x)
# --> True, as old_x and x are equal
```

In Python, variables are weakly typed, that means, you can freely reassign a variable with any type.
In the example, we could, say, assign the string `"Hi World"` to `x`.